# adding custom emoticons in iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, emoji

Please let me know if we can add custom emoticons in iOS? I have client requirement. How this functionality may achievable programmatically in iOS? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Abhishek i do my research. I know how emoji works. I need your suggestion and thoughts that can we add new custom icons or not?

Comment: i think its not cause you have to create your own Unicode charector